# Conductor of $ABC$, Frey-Hellegouarch curves, and twists

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

In page 109 of [de Weger's paper](http://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5B25%5DdW-ABCSha-QuJMathOxf%5B1998%5D.pdf), he says that for coprime $A, B, C$ the conductor $N$ of the Frey-Hellegouarch curve 
$$
E: y^2 = x(x - A)(x + B)
$$
equals $N(A,B,C)$ (product of primes dividing $ABC$ without multiplicity, and where $A + B = C$) times an absolutely bounded power of $2$. Why is this the case?

Also, on page 114, he says that the conductor $N_q$ of the twisted curve

$$
E_q : qy^2 = x(x - A)(x+B)
$$

where $q$ is a squarefree integer (ie the quadratic twist of $E$), is $lcm(N,q^2)$ and the difference in the power of $2$ is at most $2^8$. Why is this the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The computation of the conductor of the Frey curve can be found in one of the early chapters (maybe the first) of Cornell--Silverman--Stevens.
- The highest power of $2$ that can divide the conductor of an elliptic curve is $8$, if I remember correctly.
- The formula for the conductor $N_q$ (which is valid provided that $q$ is coprime to $N$) can be checked directly from the definition of the conductor in terms of $\ell$-adic Tate modules.  You can also think of it in terms of how the conductor of a newform changes when you make a twist.  This is discussed in classical language in the article of Atkin and Lehner.  It is also easily verified using 
  representation-theoretic language.

Comment: Professor Emerton, do you mind if I include you in the acknowledgements for my thesis?

Comment: @Eugene: Dear Eugene, Thank you for asking; I don't mind at all.  Best wishes,